# Setting up VS Code with Miniconda

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, miniconda

I want to set up VS Code with Miniconda. There are many tutorials on setting up VS Code with Anaconda, but none on VS Code with Miniconda. In Anaconda, you can go to the Anaconda navigator and install VS Code, but in miniconda, that is not possible.

**My question is: What are the steps to set up VS Code with Miniconda (preferably the 'base' environment)?**

I have tried it myself but I get `conda activate base` everytime I open up an integrated terminal and the code output is not displayed, only the path to the python script is displayed. This makes running python code very frustating in VS Code with miniconda.

Please let me know what are the steps to set up Miniconda with VS Code.

Comment: How do you create and use conda environment in VS Code? Have you selected the created conda environment in the lower left corner of VS Code?

Comment: @JillCheng Yes, I have. but I only see `Python 3.7.7 64-bit (conda)` instead of  `Python 3.7.7 64-bit ('base':conda)`. Also, note that I intend this question as a way to get a step-by-step process for setting up VS Code with Miniconda, so I will set it up by following the steps in the answers to see if they work.